# Pasar por parámetro a funcion PHP una variable

Tags: javascript, php, parámetros

Abro una página *PHP* que pasa un parámetro a través de Javascript:

Página_origen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var numeroficha;
function abreFicha(numero) {
    //document.getElementById("mine180").innerHTML="";
    this.numero = parseInt(numero);
    alert(numero);
    sessionStorage.setItem("sent", numero); 
    window.open('onlineappFichaMine.php','_self');
}
</script>
```

Lo recojo y compruebo que funciona con un `echo`:

Página_retorno:

```
<script>
   var a = sessionStorage.getItem("sent");
</script>

$numFicha = "<script> document.write(a) </script>";
echo $numFicha;
```

Esto devuelve `1, 2, 3, ...` en función de qué elemento he clickado en la Página_origen.

Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema, es que en la Página_retorno ejecuto la función:

```
public function get_mineral($numFicha) {

    $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM MINERALESES WHERE NUMEROMINE='$numFicha'");

    while($filas=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $this->mineralesc[]=$filas;
    }
    return $this->mineralesc;
}
```

Siendo el campo de *MySQL* de tipo `INT`.

De forma que, volviendo a probar, por ejemplo con el `10`, me funciona el método:

```
get_mineral(10);
```

Que me devuelve correctamente el array que busco. Sin embargo, al introducir el parámetro, la variable que traigo de Javascript, `$numFicha`, pese a que el `echo` me devuelve también `1, 2, 3... 10, ...` no funciona:

```
get_mineral($numFicha);
```

He tratado de hacer todo tipo de conversiones, tanto en el *Javascript* que envía el valor como en el *PHP* que lo recoge antes de que ejecutara el método.

Comment: No he dicho nada. Pensaba que habia visto el problema pero he releido y he visto que no era ese el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando llamas a una pagina php por parametros lo capturas por GET o POST 
en Página_origen cambia eso y agrega algo como:

```
<a href="Página_retorno.php?ficha=1">click en ficha</a>
```

en Pagina_Retorno deberias de tener algo como :

```
$numFicha = intval($_GET['ficha']);get_mineral($numFicha);
```

Como recomendacion para entrar al mundo php aprendete esto: $_GET parametros de url $_POST parametros que pasas por formulario tipo post

Hay muchas mas!! pero para empezar lee un poco mas de lo que te comente.

Comment: El problema es que creo que no puedo usar un formulario.Son 180 filas generadas dinámicamente con código php que lee mi base de datos.La aplicación más tarde, según la búsqueda del usuario, puede que muestre solo 10 minerales y no 180, por lo que no puedo introducir ?ficha=x porque a lo mejor al principio el mineral está en la posición 57 y luego pasa a estar en la 2, y quiero que en ambos casos me abra su ficha.La única manera que he encontrado es que la ficha se abra en el evento on click de las filas, haciendo: <?php "<tr onclick='abreFicha(" . $numeroFicha . ")'><td>" .$valores "</td></tr>

Comment: haz esto: ?php "<tr href='Página_retorno.php?ficha=" . $numeroFicha . "'><td>" .$valores "</td></tr>  haz un echo de numeroFicha puede que este sucia la variable

Comment: Hecho, solucionado. Con quitar el aspecto de link con css la aplicación quedará perfecta sin tanto lío con los scripts; ¡gracias!.